# I want to recall a python function in vs code but always an error happens. how can I solve it?

Tags: python, function

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n<=1:
        return_value=1
        print(return_value)
    else:
        return_value=n*(factorial(n-1))
        print(return_value)
        
factorial(10)
```

the error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: it is called **recursion** not recall

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is that you're not returning any value at the end of function call. So in the statement `return_value=n*(factorial(n-1))` where you are expecting `10*factorial(9)` you're getting `return_value=10*None` which results in Invalid operation as you can see in the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

As * doesn't work with `None` and `int` as operand.

Solution is simple add a return statement

```
def factorial(n):
    if n<=1:
        return_value=1
        print(return_value)
    else:
        return_value=n*factorial(n-1)
        print(return_value)
    return return_value

factorial(10)
```

Comment: Thank you.it worked ,but has shown all numbers ,I want just the last one             1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800

Comment: Remove the all `print` statement and replace last line with `print(factorial(10))`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your factorial program is incorrect that is not my concern if you ask me then I will tell you now come to the main point, whenever the function is used you can return something so it can show an output, as your input value and function take that value and apply functionalities but after completion function doesn't know how it can return your result. so the **return** keyword helps to do it.

```
def factorial(n):
if n<=1:
    return_value=1
    print(return_value)
    return return_value
else:
    n=n*factorial(n-1)
    print(n)
    return n
    
factorial(10)
```